# Jquery code to resize images not working

Tags: jquery

I am a total jquery newb and I have a deadline for this project so please don't laugh.

I am trying to make this jquery code work:

```
function resize_images(){
   var def = $(".defx img").height(); // get the desired height

   $(".model").each(function() { // loop through all images inside model divs
       var images = $(this).find("img"); // find the image
       var height = images.height(); // find the image height
       if (height > def){  images.css("height: "+def+"px !important"); } // if the image height is larger than the default add a css rule
   });  
}
```

Any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: The def value is working, tested it - the each function does not loop through properly; I believe I get only the first img value

Comment: What is the "!important", in the css..?

Comment: The 'px !important' bit isn't necessary.

Comment: Why not just use `max-height`?

Comment: Also, can you set a css attribute using a string? Try css({height: x}) or css('height', x)

Comment: `images.height()` only returns the height of the first image. You have to loop over the images themselves.

Comment: Its a em based layout and I have set the height to auto and I can't use max height

Comment: Ty Joseph, this is what I suspect also,how do I do this?

Comment: you are not looping all images, you are currently looping all div's with .model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only checking the height of the first `img`. Loop over the images themselves:

```
function resize_images() {
    var maxHeight = $(".defx img").height();
    $(".model img").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ( $this.height() > maxHeight ) {
            $this.css('height', maxHeight);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Should I keep this? $(this).find("img");

Comment: It shows you have dexterity in coding... I am just a webmaster and I get to code every no and then... it will take some time and training :)  ty again